# why does this reader read off strange bits of data?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read a text file, i'm using fileImputStream, and reading all the lines into a single String then outputing it into the console (System.out)

When I try to read the humanSerf.txt, it gives me this in the consol:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 symbol=HS\
strength=15\
agility=13\
constitution=7\
wisdom=9\
intelligence=5}
```

in the text file, it says this:

```
symbol=HS
strength=15
agility=13
constitution=7
wisdom=9
intelligence=5
```

How do I make the weird text disappear?

this is the code i'm using, please help

```
try{
                  // Open the file that is the first 
                  // command line parameter
                  FileInputStream read = new FileInputStream("resources/monsters/human/humanSerf.txt");
                  // Get the object of DataInputStream
                  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(read);
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                  String strLine;
                  //Read File Line By Line
                  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                  // Print the content on the console
                  System.out.println (strLine);
                  }
                  //Close the input stream
                  in.close();
                    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  }
```

How do I make the weird text disappear? 
ps, this was done in mac textedditor

Comment: It seems that this is not a plain text-file. With which editor are you viewing it?

Comment: It seems the text might have been copied of a RTF document. It really depends on what editor you are using to view the properties file. Try opening it in a plain text editor such as notepad and you should see the strange formatting there as well.

Comment: It seems to be not a plain text-file, but a RTF (Rich text format) File which can store additional data for formatting etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your text file is not plain text but rather a [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) file which supports formatting. When you view it you probably use a tool which supports RTF, such as TextEdit. If you view it with less or cat you should also see the RTF markup.