# Reading JSON Response from resource stored in app

Tags: android, json

I am reading json response from the .json file that I have stored inside the app. This is what I am doing

```
private String readJSONResponse(){
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_data);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return writer.toString();
    }
```

When ever I am trying to read the file is beginning with some data like `11-11 11:30:57.789: I/System.out(3200): response that has been readed {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
11-11 11:30:57.789: I/System.out(3200): {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
11-11 11:30:57.789: I/System.out(3200): {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
11-11 11:30:57.789: I/System.out(3200): \margl1440\margr1440\vieww16160\viewh10840\viewkind0
11-11 11:30:57.789: I/System.out(3200): \deftab720
11-11 11:30:57.789: I/System.out(3200): \pard\pardeftab720\ql\qnatural
11-11 11:30:57.799: I/System.out(3200): \f0\fs24 \cf0 \{"status": [\{"response": 13, //this is what is stored in my app`

How do I get rid of these data and the special charcters like '\'(please check its before response.)

Comment: I think you have saved the json_data file using WordPad or Microsoft word. Try saving the file using Notepad. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443860/why-does-this-reader-read-off-strange-bits-of-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this
1. make "yourfilename.txt" file on your assert folder and put your json respone.
2. now run below code
private String readJSONResponse(){
        Writer writer=null;
        try{
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream is = assetManager.open("yourfilename.txt");
            writer = new StringWriter();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];

            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return writer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String tempStr = null;

try {
    while ((tempStr = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(tempStr);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.v("", "JSON DATA is " + sb.toString());
```

This worked for me. I put test.json file in raw folder.  Make sure your json is valid. You can test your json file on http://jsonlint.com/