# Manipulating Arabic text files Java

Tags: java, file-io, arabic

I'm trying to read an Arabic text file using IntelliJ, while there were no errors but the output isn't readable. when trying simple output statement in Arabic. 
This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "myFile.txt";

    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;

    System.out.println("أهلا يا عالم");

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        Reader fileReader =
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("myFile.txt"), "utf-8");

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);}
     }
}
```

This is some of my output:

```
    أهلا يا عالم
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
{\fonttbl\f0\froman\fcharset0 TimesNewRomanPSMT;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10980\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\tx10171\pardeftab720\qr\partightenfactor0\f0\fs24\cf0 1\\uc0\u1576 \u1587 \u1605  \u1575 \u1604 \u1604 \u1607  \u1575 \u1604 \u1585 \u1581 \u1605 \u1606  \u1575 \u1604 \u1585 \u1581 \u1610 \u1605  \u1575 \u1604 \u1581 \u1605
```

These are some lines of myFile:

1
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم الحمد لله رب العالمين الرحمن الرحيم مالك يوم الدين

2
وصلى الله وسلم على النبي المصطفى وآله وصحبه ومن اقتفى

Thanks,

Comment: It will be easier to identify the issue if you can share sample myfile.txt

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443860/why-does-this-reader-read-off-strange-bits-of-data

Comment: As @DevashishJaiswal shared, it seems to be some issue with your file. For normal test, I just copied the line n tried to execute you shared and it worked fine:

jshell>  Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("outputTxt.txt"),"utf-8"); 
fileReader ==> java.io.InputStreamReader@610694f1
jshell> BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
bufferedReader ==> java.io.BufferedReader@43814d18
jshell> while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(line);}
أهلا يا عالمأهلا يا عالمأهلا يا عالمأهلا يا عالمأهلا يا ع

Comment: Again, tried the sample lines you shared and they worked fine as well:  وصلى الله وسلم على النبي المصطفى وآله وصحبه ومن اقتفى بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم الحمد لله رب العالمين الرحمن الرحيم مالك يوم الدين

Please check your file is not formatted one and is plain txt

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal Yes, it was from an RTF then change it to TXT, I'll try to edit this, thanks!

Comment: @AmanChhabra Thank you so much, It worked just great!